# Why isn't a static constructor invoked on a class used as a generic type parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, static-constructor

Given the following classes:

```
public class Foo {
    static Foo() {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo is being constructed");
    }
}

public class Bar {
    public void ReferenceFooAsGenericTypeParameter<T>() {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo is being referenced as a generic type parameter");
    }
}

public class SampleClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new Bar().ReferenceFooAsGenericTypeParameter<Foo>();
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Foo is being referenced as a generic type parameter
```

This makes sense, according to the spec:

> A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.

But I'm curious why the static constructor is not invoked when the type is referenced as a generic type parameter.

Comment: Good question mate, this one bit me today

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would it need to be?

The point of the static constructor being called normally is to make sure that any state set up within the static constructor is initialized before it's first used.

Just using `Foo` as a type argument doesn't make use of any state within it, so there's no need for the static constructor to be called.

You might want to try creating a static variable initializer with side effects (e.g. a method call which *then* prints to the console) and removing the static constructor - that [can affect the timing of initialization significantly](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0/) in some cases. It *may* trigger it here.

Comment: I figured as much.  Thanks for the clarification, and the link.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you can't actually use the type contents in any meaningful way just by inclusion as a generic type parameter, the type needs to have something done to it to warrant a static constructor being called.

And you're correct that this is in line with the specification. Section 10.12 (Static Constructors) states:

> The execution of a static constructor
>   is triggered by the first of the following events to occur within an
>   application domain:
>
> ·         An instance of the class type is created.
>
> ·         Any of the static members of the class type are referenced.

Use as a generic type parameter is neither of these.

Comment: The question already acknowledges that the behaviour is according to the spec, but asks why the spec is written the way it is.

Comment: @hvd Thanks, missed that. Answer changed.

Answer (score 0):

The thing to note here is that in `new Bar().ReferenceFooAsGenericTypeParameter<Foo>();` you have created an object of type Bar, neither your main nor **Bar** have create an instance of `Foo` nor has any of it's members been accessed, in the case presented, the type itself merely being passed as a param.